# Biblatex.sty Error: \bibhang already defined

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

I decided to test `biblatex` with my document, but unfortunately, I am provided with the following error:

```
..\biblatex.sty! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
```

Whereas my tex-file is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[medium]{titlesec}
\usepackage{authordate1-4}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,sorting=nyt,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{msources.bib}

\begin{document}

%Main part
\input{./1_introduction/1_introduction.tex}

Test \citet{tang2012}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bib-file contains the test reference and is placed in the same directory.
Lastly, I compile the code using *TeXMaker* and the following procedure:

```
PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf
```

Reinstalling the `biblatex` package has not fixed the error, nor has switching to `natbib` solved it. In fact, it remains the same while pointing towards the `natbib.sty`

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Don't use the authordate1-4 package.

Comment: Huff.. it's been a long day. Sorry, and thanks for your help! This answer is - of course - correct.

Comment: `subfigure` ought not be used: it is obsolete. Consider `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: Can you post a  fully compilable code?

Comment: @moewe: I added an short answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `authordate1-4` package. It clashes with biblatex.